# Is there a way to submit spark job on different server running master

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, airflow

We have a requirement to schedule spark jobs, since we are familiar with apache-airflow we want to go ahead with it to create different workflows. I searched web but did not find a step by step guide to schedule spark job on airflow and option to run them on different server running master.

Answer to this will be highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There are 3 ways you can submit Spark jobs using Apache Airflow remotely:

(1) **Using `SparkSubmitOperator`**: This operator expects you have a spark-submit binary and YARN client config setup on our Airflow server. It invokes the spark-submit command with given options, blocks until the job finishes and returns the final status. The good thing is, it also streams the logs from the spark-submit command stdout and stderr.

You really only need to configure a yarn-site.xml file, I believe, in order for `spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode` client to work.

Once an Application Master is deployed within YARN, then Spark is running locally to the Hadoop cluster.

If you really want, you could add a `hdfs-site.xml` and `hive-site.xml` to be submitted as well from Airflow (if that's possible), but otherwise at least `hdfs-site.xml` files should be picked up from the YARN container classpath

(2) **Using `SSHOperator`**: Use this operator to run bash commands on a remote server (using SSH protocol via paramiko library) like `spark-submit`. The benefit of this approach is you don't need to copy the `hdfs-site.xml` or maintain any file.

(3) **Using `SimpleHTTPOperator` with Livy**: Livy is an open source REST interface for interacting with Apache Spark from anywhere. You just need to have REST calls.

I personally prefer **SSHOperator** :)

Comment: But in case of SSHOperator we need to run airflow on same server of spark master node. Isn't it?

Comment: No, that is `BashOperator`. With `SSHOperator` you can run bash commands on a remote server. I have updated my answer to include this info.

Comment: The SSHOperator does not work in my case. The Spark-submit job runs forever and when i run the same job from shell it executes within 5 minutes. Kindly suggest. Link :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56988228/running-spark-job-using-paramiko-library

Comment: @kaxil With Approach #2 SSHOperator, even though the task is ran successfully, Airflow marks it as Failed. And I ran with test code: ```command='bash tmp.sh',``` even this would return as Failed in Airflow. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

We can use any of these below options to submit the spark job in Airflow

1. SparkSubmitOperator.
2. PythonOperator
3. BashOperator

Below is the link which explains us with the code for running the airflow using these jobs
https://medium.com/codex/executing-spark-jobs-with-apache-airflow-3596717bbbe3

Comment: I would consider this a duplicate answer. You mention 3 methods that a technically the same as in the other answer, except you leave the explanation to a link.