# how to remote submit spark jobs to Azure HDInsights cluster without Livy

Tags: azure, apache-spark, airflow, azure-hdinsight

I want to submit spark job to azure hdInsights cluster from airflow, I don't want to use livy as it doesn't accumulate logs on airflow. Is it possible to do remotely submit job. SSH is 1 option but if job is long running it might break connection. Is there any other option? 
Note - Airflow cluster is remote cluster, it's not colocated with spark cluster.

Comment: have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53344713/3679900) and also the 4th point [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54092691/3679900)

Comment: Already checked with both of them, None of them is useful, as Azure Hdinsights cluster doesn't expose  those ports.