# How to Submit a Spark Job from Airflow, where both are on different server?

Tags: apache-spark, airflow, hadoop-yarn

I have a requirement, where I need to submit a spark job using Airflow.
Airflow and Hadoop clusters are on different server.

Currently, simple solution to use use a BashOperator and ssh into Hadoop cluster machine and submit the job.

But,I want to also explore the SparkSubmitOperaror.

I have gone through many articles and stackoverflow question, but did not found any detailed explanation on how to setup Airflow server for this to work.
I found below stackoverflow question, where he mentions that,we need to have spark-binaries and need to configure yarn-site.xml on Airflow machine.

[Is there a way to submit spark job on different server running master](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53344285/is-there-a-way-to-submit-spark-job-on-different-server-running-master)

But, nowhere ,I found how to setup this things.

Answer (score 0):

As written in the other post

> You really only need to configure a yarn-site.xml file

This defines the YARN ResourceManager address(es)

Similarly, core-site.xml defines the Namenode address(es) / nameservice for HDFS.

You'll need to package both files in any node that'll be capable of running Spark code using an environment variable `SPARK_CONF_DIR`... And, as documented on the SparkSubmitOperator, you'll need to install Spark on each Airflow worker, then ensure `spark-submit` is on the OS `PATH`; in other words, it's the exact same as BashOperator, but provides way to explicitly call/configure the Spark executable. You don't need SSH to run Spark.

---

Other than that, you may need to configure OS firewall rules, or network routes, but that's not specific to Hadoop or Airflow